# I'd like to reduce the size of an image that the user created by 60%

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
private synchronized void produceSignatureImage(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt, final String envStrFileName) {
    final String es = envStrFileName;
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                bufferedImage.createGraphics().drawImage(img, 0, 0, TrusteeSignature.this);
                String filename = sdf.format(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())) + ".jpg";
                File outputfile = new File(IMAGE_FILE_PATH + filename);
                String fullPath = outputfile.getAbsolutePath();
                if (isNotesLocal()) {
                    NotesThread.sinitThread();
                }
                s = openSession();
                s.setEnvironmentVar(envStrFileName, fullPath);
                ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", outputfile);
                Button b = (Button) evt.getSource();
                b.setEnabled(false);
                clear();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (s != null) {
                        TrusteeSignature.this.closeSession(s);
                    }
                } catch (NotesException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (isNotesLocal()) {
                    NotesThread.stermThread();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

This is working well, but I'd like to reduce the size of the image by 60% from 500x250 to 200x150 fixed.

I don't need the original sized image that we're writing to the file system and would be just as happy to reduce the file size before it gets written.  I found the following code elsewhere on this site.

```
   /**
 * we want the x and o to be resized when the JFrame is resized
 *
 * @param originalImage an x or an o. Use cross or oh fields.
 *
 * @param biggerWidth
 * @param biggerHeight
 */
private Image resizeToBig(Image originalImage, int biggerWidth, int biggerHeight) {
    int type = BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB;

    BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(biggerWidth, biggerHeight, type);
    Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();

    g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, biggerWidth, biggerHeight, this);
    g.dispose();

    return resizedImage;
}
```

I see that the image is being made larger.  I'm assuming that reducing the size of the image can also be done by the following two lines of code once I've set the 60% resize numbers as variables:

```
BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(biggerWidth, biggerHeight, type);
Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
```

What I'm unsure of is this:  Because I only want to write the 40% sized image to the OS, where in my code do I resize before i write the JPG file to the OS?

Yes, I'm a Java newbie!

Answer (score 0):

Try this at the start of your `try` block:

```
Image resizedImage = img.getScaledInstance(newWidth, newHeight, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(newWidth, newHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
bufferedImage.createGraphics().drawImage(resizedImage, 0, 0, TrusteeSignature.this);
```

...where `newWidth` and `newHeight` equal your desired resized dimensions, e.g. `200` and `150`.

Documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance-int-int-int-